# Adding the value using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

For any **incoming request**

```
<soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<OrderCreate xmlns="urn:cidx:names:specification:ces:schema:all:5:1:1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Header>
        <ThisDocumentIdentifier>
            <DocumentIdentifier>72750037</DocumentIdentifier>
        </ThisDocumentIdentifier>
        <ThisDocumentDateTime>
            <DateTime DateTimeQualifier="On">2014-12-01T00:00:00Z</DateTime>
        </ThisDocumentDateTime>
    </Header>
</OrderCreate>
</soapenv:Body>
```

I need to add this line here.

```
<OrderCreate xmlns:ces="urn:cidx:names:specification:ces:schema:all:5:1:1" Version="2.0.2">
```

**Below is the code**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ces="urn:cidx:names:specification:ces:schema:all:5:1:1" xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions" version="1.0" extension-element-prefixes="dp">
<xsl:template match="*[local-name()='OrderCreate']">
    <OrderCreate Version="2.0.2">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </OrderCreate>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="attribute::*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For some reason its not working. Can anyone please point me where I am doing it wrong

**I am getting output.**

```
 <OrderCreate
xmlns="urn:cidx:names:specification:ces:schema:all:5:1:1"
xmlns:tns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
>
```

Comment: What is not working? What is the current result you obtain?

Comment: Please check my updated comment

Comment: Is it possible that you've overly pruned your example?  XSLT won't invent namespace declarations that it's not seen.

Comment: @kjhughes the XML was really big so I just copied the relevant information. The code I have does other changes as well. However when I tested here http://xsltransform.net/pPqsHTo the same code works. I am not sure where I am doing it wrong because when I used the same thing in Gateway that I work on its not working.

Comment: Your test case also works with Saxon 6.5.5.  Try to find a case that exhibits your problem and still fails so we can reproduce it and help you fix it.  Two other tips for you:  Be aware of how to use `exclude-result-prefixes`.  Also, if at all possible, work with namespaces rather than try to eliminate them; they appear messy at first but work well in the long run.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think I have a found bug in the gateway and I will open the ticket to get this resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making a couple of mistakes:

- you are creating elements with no namespace
- you are not matching the attributes, so `DateTimeQualifier` is not copied in the output

This stylesheet copies all elements and attributes, keeping their namespace, and adds `Version="2.0.2"` to `OrderCreate`:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:ces="urn:cidx:names:specification:ces:schema:all:5:1:1"
    xmlns="urn:cidx:names:specification:ces:schema:all:5:1:1">
    <xsl:template match="ces:OrderCreate">
        <OrderCreate Version="2.0.2">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </OrderCreate>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="* | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="attribute::*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```